# EmailComposer Plugin is not working with Xcode 3.2.6 and Cordova 1.5.0

Tags: xcode, cordova

I need your help with getting the EmailComposer plugin to work with Cordova 1.5.0 on Xcode 3.2.6.
I did everything I read:

1. Added the .m and .h files to the plugins folder (By dragging the files to folder in Xcode and also by adding existing files to the folder).
2. Added the .js file to the www folder, by adding it in finder.
3. Added this reference to my index.html: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="EmailComposer.js"></script>` right after the Cordova reference.
4. Added the plugin entry to the Cordova.plist file. Key: EmailComposer, type: String, value: EmailComposer.
5. Changed the code inside the plugin .h and .m files to work with Cordova (and not Phonegap) as described here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/381
6. Call the show method like this: 
   `function sendmail()
   {
       window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("Subject","PlainTextBody", "recipient,recipient", "ccRecipient", "bccRecipient",false);
   }`

The `sendmail()` function is getting called.

After doing all of this, I still cant get this to work, when calling the `sendmail()` function, nothing happens.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem soved!
I found another little something need to be changed in the .js file.
Take a look at it: 
https://github.com/devgeeks/phonegap-plugins/commit/be221a9a839c3bc5374704a311fab4aa9c7fb58f
And now its working.